# Can I limit a class or method in a Portable Class Library to a specific platform?

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I'm creating a Portable Class Library and Targeting .Net 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.

Can I limit a class or method to a specific target? Like a method can only be called from a .Net 4.5 project, and not from a Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Is this possible?

Comment: That rather defeats the point of a PCL project.  If you are going to force yourself to create separate builds then just don't bother with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using directives that specify those platforms. Now I'm not entirely sure if there is a .NET 4.5 directive automatically available but as far as I know there are the

`#SILVERLIGHT`, `#WINDOWS_PHONE`, `#WP8` and `#NETFX_CORE` directives available.

You can use them like this:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
   int x = 1;
# else
   int x = 2;
#endif
```

In your situation you would place them around the method so the method would only get compiled if the right projects are targetted.

I believe `#NETFX_CORE` only indicates it is Windows 8 and not .NET. There might be .NET specific directives but they aren't set automatically for the projects you're referring to (probably because those use WinRT, not .NET per sé).

However [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time) indicates that you could set it with a custom directive:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.0' ">
    RUNNING_ON_4
</DefineConstants>
```

Comment: So I cannot just compile the library once and then use it all the time? Do I have to include the source project to every project I want to use this library with?

Comment: No, using these directives allow you to only compile it once.

Answer (score 2):

This is feasible using [**Dependency Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

For instance, you may use contextual binding with [**Ninject**](http://www.ninject.org/) to inject the appropriate type implementation so that this method call shall do nothing whilst another implementation shall do what is intended.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
    public abstract void MyMethod() { }
}

public class MyDerivedDotNet45Class : MyBaseclass() {
    public override void MyMethod() { // Does something... }
}

public class MyDerivedWindowsPhoneClass : MyBaseClass() {
    public override void MyMethod() { // Does nothing... }
}

public class MyWorkingProcessClass {
    public MyWorkingProcessClass(MyBaseClass baseClass) {
        dependency = baseClass;
    }

    public void MethodThatShallDoSomethingOnlyWhenDotNet45() {
        dependency.MyMethod();
    }

    private readonly MyBaseClass dependency;
}
```

So depending on which class you inject, your program shall either do something or nothing.

**Under .Net 4.5**

```
var workingClass = new MyWorkingProcessClass(new MyDerivedDotNet45Class());
wokringClass.MethodThatShallDoSomethingOnlyWhenDotNet45();
```

This shall do something as stated in the derived class.

**Under Windows Phone**

```
var workingClass = new MyWorkingProcessClass(new MyDerivedWindowsPhoneClass());
workingClass.MethodThatShallDoSomethingOnlyWhenDotNet45();
```

This shall do nothing as stated in the derived class.

**Using Ninject**

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842342/162167) provides with a good example of using [**Contextual Binding**](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

This is in the [**Composition Root**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) that you shall build your object composition so that it knows what to inject where and when.